# Restructuring the object using different name [Object manipulation]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a use case where I have to restructure the object. Initial I have this object

```
{ 
    name: 'Tommy Kerar',
    mandatoryRequirements : [{
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",
          relativeUrl:
            "2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=HjMt%2Fpo1xc%2Bzt%2BeWaN%2FpU3vpY4A%3D",
        }],
    postGrad: [
        {
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        }
    ],
    yourDocuments: [
         {
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        }
    ]
}
```

As a result output I want something like this
Major changes are I want to make one single array out form above object, with name as username, And folder names as per the above object keys with names in the below expected output.

PS:  I am new to JS world. Previously with Python.

```
  const dd = { 
    name: 'Tommy Kerar',
    mandatoryRequirements : [{
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",
          relativeUrl:
            "2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=HjMt%2Fpo1xc%2Bzt%2BeWaN%2FpU3vpY4A%3D",
        }],
    postGrad: [
        {
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        }
    ],
    yourDocuments: [
         {
          name: "dummy.pdf",
          relativeUrl: "b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D",
        },
        {
          name: "Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",
          relativeUrl:
            "6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",
          url:
            "https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D",
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried, But stuck at adding `username` and `folder` adding to the array list.

```
let newA = [];

newA = dd.postGrad
newA = dd.yourDocuments
newA = dd.mandatoryRequirements


console.log(newA)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Comment: you can use `Array.reduce()`, or loop over the object and construct your new object as well

Comment: @boxdox I tried but unable to manipulate it the way I require. :(

Comment: please share a MRP (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as mentioned by @Andy

Comment: You should add the code you've tried to your question. It maybe a simple issue that we can help resolve, but we don't general write other people's code for them.

Comment: @Andy updated question to what I tried until now

Comment: @boxdox I have udpated question. as per minimak rep example

Comment: you're trying to assign a variable to array, which will overwrite it. i recommend you read about Array methods like map, filter and reduce, and update the sample code again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.entries, Array.isArray, flat & map..

I've done an example here with comments for each part.

eg.

```js
var data={name:"Tommy Kerar",mandatoryRequirements:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"},{name:"ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",relativeUrl:"2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=HjMt%2Fpo1xc%2Bzt%2BeWaN%2FpU3vpY4A%3D"}],postGrad:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"}],yourDocuments:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"}]};

console.log(
  Object.entries(data)  //get entries  key,value
    .filter(([_,v]) => Array.isArray(v))  //filter out values that are not arrays
    .map(([k,v]) =>   //use this map to do outer loop
      v.map(v2 => ({username: data.name, 
        foldername: 
          k.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2') //ex. split postGrad to `post Grad`
          .replace(/^./, v => v.toUpperCase()),  //now uppercase that first letter `Post Grad`
        ...v2}))) //map our sub arrays
    .flat()  //finally flattern
);
```

For new users to Javascript, the above code might look daunting.
But it's not as bad as it looks, especially if we break it down.  So below I'm also doing another version that's longer but should be much easier for new comers to JS to understand.

I've commented out some console.log's, you can un-comment to see each stage.  But basically the code is doing exactly the same as the first snippet.

```js
var data={name:"Tommy Kerar",mandatoryRequirements:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"},{name:"ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",relativeUrl:"2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2e07b606-d1a0-4587-b8bb-c8f4b3927483ales-nesetril-Im7lZjxeLhg-unsplash.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=HjMt%2Fpo1xc%2Bzt%2BeWaN%2FpU3vpY4A%3D"}],postGrad:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"}],yourDocuments:[{name:"dummy.pdf",relativeUrl:"b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/b9dde810-4935-4471-a22d-bdaf61e8bd62dummy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=jefI4SMA0LlVutoBDkVZdDchSSY%3D"},{name:"Sell the Solution, Not the Product.png",relativeUrl:"6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell the Solution, Not the Product..png",url:"https://upaged-file-store-prod.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/6397c507-0d05-4cd7-8e4b-371249f72dbeSell%20the%20Solution%2C%20Not%20the%20Product..png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRO4YTL2YDUPVPPW&Expires=1625593013&Signature=96fCwM%2FOz%2F60nt%2FCdhkdbM%2B04oo%3D"}]};


//lets get our data into the form of key value pairs.
//eg.  [
//  ["name", "Tommoy Kerar"],
//  ["mandatoryRequirements", [........]
//]
const keyValues = Object.entries(data);
//console.log(keyValues);

//next lets filter out array items who's value is not an array
//ps.  second array element [1] of each keyvalue is the value
const keyValuesArrayOnly = keyValues.filter(a => Array.isArray(a[1]));
//console.log(keyValuesArrayOnly);

//a simple function to convert camel case to a kind of Title
function camelCaseToTitle(txt) {
  return txt.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2') //ex. split postGrad to `post Grad`
    .replace(/^./, v => v.toUpperCase()); //uppercase first letter  `Post Grad`
}
//console.log(camelCaseToTitle('postGrad'));

//let's now map our values, here we use a map inside a map to copy the values across
//the reason we can't do later after flatterning is that we will loose the foldername
//links otherwise.  By doing a map inside a map, you then have the foldername scoped 
//for the inner array.
const mappedValues = keyValuesArrayOnly.
  map(([foldername, items]) => 
    items.map(value => ({
      username: data.name,
      foldername: camelCaseToTitle(foldername),
      ...value  //spread all the values on this new object.
    }))
  );
//console.log(mappedValues);

//finally let's flatten our results, as it's currently in form [[item,item], [item,item]]
//and we want [item, item, item, item]

const result = mappedValues.flat();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, But look out for the folder name, That is missing. Which needs to alter as well.

Comment: I am more confused in assigning the Folder Names. Really Not sure how to put it as I expect. (See in above code, The Input and Output for Folders)

Comment: @MariaAndre  Oh, yes. missed that bit, you just need another map to loop the inner arrays..  And use `Object.entries` so you can extract the folder name..

Comment: Last question - How an I change the folder name `mandatoryRequirements ` to Mandatory Requirements, `postGrad ` to Post Graduation, `yourDocuments ` to Your Documents ?

Comment: @MariaAndre  A couple of regEx's on the folder name will convert `postGrad` to `Post Grad`, updated answer

Answer (score -1):

The best thing that comes to my mind is to add the elements you have on each array to a new one with the desired properties set. I am not sure if any function call exists to make this process easier, I believe you will have to use `forEach` method on the arrays.